# Why is my code failing on useEffect whenever I update my JSON data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a function that receives JSON data from my server, I use the `{jsonData.map((element) => renderComponents(element, jsonData))}` function to loop through it and send each object to
`renderComponents`  function along with the full JSON data, and this function has a switch statement with multiple cases for different `element.componentType`(from the JSON data).

this is the switch statement

```
function renderComponent(element, jsonData) {
switch (element.componentType) {
    case 'TypeOne':
      return (
        <div>
         </div>
      );
    break;
    
    case 'TypeTwo':

     useEffect(() => {
            console.log("test");
        }, [jsonData]);

    return (
        <div>
         </div>
      );
    break;
}
}
```

it works the first time it loads, but whenever I use another function to update the jsonData and add a new element of `TypeTwo` I get an error before the `useEffect` executes.
I can assure you the updated jsonData is fine and when I load a new `TypeOne`it gets loaded perfectly, just the issue with `TypeTwo`

here's the error code

```
Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by MainFunction. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks: https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks

   Previous render            Next render
   ------------------------------------------------------
1. useState                   useState
2. useEffect                  useEffect
3. undefined                  useEffect
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

this is my json

```
{
     "title": "MY element",
     "id": 3262405,
     "componentType": "TypeOne",
},
{
     "title": "MY element two",
     "id": 9998454,
     "componentType": "TypeTwo",
}
```

the issue is with useEffect, it doesn't get called and the code stops right there

Comment: One golden rule in React, hooks have to run in the same order, every single render. You can't use a `useEffect` inside a switch, the solution though is really simple, split your code into multiple components, your switch statement can then `return <TypeOne/>` or `<TypeTwo/>` so then your `useEffect` can be inside `TypeTwo` component.

Comment: From the [link](https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks) in the error message - Functions whose names start with use are called Hooks in React.  Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split these components outside the primary function to avoid unnecessary rendering, I usually create a new file for each option.

There are some caveats when using hooks, they cannot be called conditionally or in a sub-function like in your sample...
more info: https://react.dev/reference/react

```
function ComponentTypeOne() {
  return <div>TypeOne Component</div>
}



function ComponentTypeTwo({ data }: { data: any }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('test', data)
  }, [data])

  return <div>TypeTwo Conponent</div>
}



function renderComponent(element, jsonData) {
  switch (element.componentType) {
    case 'TypeOne':
      return <ComponentTypeOne />

    case 'TypeTwo':
      return <ComponentTypeTwo data={jsonData} />
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to:

```js
function renderComponent(element, jsonData) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("test");
  }, [jsonData]);
  switch (element.componentType) {
    case 'TypeOne':
      return ( <
        div >
        <
        /div>
      );
      break;

    case 'TypeTwo':
      return ( <
        div >
        <
        /div>
      );
      break;
  }
}
```

As useEffect has to be called at the top level of the functional component.

Comment: Thank you, but I already tried but it doesn't work, especially that the intended code inside useEffect is only for the TypeTwo case,  in this question i used console.log just to fill the hook and the issue isn't in the code inside.

Comment: I understand, but I think a call of useEffect inside a switch-case statement will always lead to an error. It would be useful to know what exactly you're trying to do, so maybe someone knows an alternative way to achieve that.

Comment: it works when it gets loaded at first and the code inside it executes normally, only when I update the json that it fails, the code inside the useeffect is pretty simple, it looks for div elements with the id of the element and it increases the width and other things, it's basic and that code only applies to elements of TypeTwo. I tried everything I could, asked friends, even chatgpt ... but thank you I appreciate you trying, I don't know how else I can explain so I'll keep digging further and see how to fix it :)

Comment: It is logical that the first time the runtime-error occurs is when renderComponent is called with an element with the attribute componentType === "TypeTwo" because only then the wrong placed useEffect function is called. You could use two different functional components, one with useEffect and one without. The surrounding component could then use a switch-case-statement and return either the one or the other component.